# The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

Tags: vue.js, tomcat, cors

I have a CORS problem that I believe had all settings configured correctly. The request passed OPTIONS preflight without a problem but the POST request has a CORS issue of CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing. I have no idea why this would happen as other GET request and OPTIONS request are working fine. The api requires a Cookie and X-X-XSRF-TOKEN. And I can access these api data in POSTMAN.

Is it because of the request payload?

My Chrome Error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://example.com:8080/login' from origin 'http://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

I have added:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
axios.defaults.crossDomain = true
```

My post request:

```
async submitLogin() {
  const headers = { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" };
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("username", "example1");
  formData.append("password", "example1");
  axios
    .post("http://example.com:8080/login", formData, {
      headers: headers,
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
},
```

My Tomcat web.xml Config:

```
<filter>
      <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>http://example.com</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Cache-Control,Accept-Language,Accept-Encoding,x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, Accept,Content-Length, Connection,Referer,client-security-token,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,Cookie,Authorization,Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,X-XSRF-TOKEN,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
      </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>

      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
        <param-value>10</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

[Successfully passed OPTIONS Preflight Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPgF9.png)
[Request Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kxNJ.png)

Comment: the server you are asking for data needs to have you on its whitelist. 
other option is to use a proxy.

apart from this i would not recommend you to allow all origins with a *. 

on production, setup your backend for you frontend as allowed origin, in devlopment use  proxy.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: @Deniz Thank you for your reply, I would try to work with the proxy in development first. I have set up the cors.allowed.origins and it has the fontend domain. I don't understand why it passed the OPTIONS preflight but not the actual POST request.

Answer (score -1):

Try modifying your `web.xml` config's `cors.allowed.origins` param to `*`.

You're generally pretty safe with GET requests unless the receiving server's settings are strict — GETs aren't discriminated against in the CORS universe in the same way POST requests are. That may be why you're noticing the discrepancy you mentioned. Postman also doesn't face the same restrictions that a browser does.

If changing `cors.allowed.origins` doesn't work, try inspecting the error message in the devtools console in more than one browser; sometimes one browser is more specific than the next and will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the GET part. Sadly, I have tried setting the cors.allowed.origins to * but not working. I think it is not allowed for request with credential. Firefox shows: Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’).